# Why CellList with ButtonCell column controled by cellListDataProvider behave bizarrely? is it a Gwt bug?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using Gwt 2.5, i got this very simple code:

```
ButtonCell buttonCell=new ButtonCell();
CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(buttonCell);
ListDataProvider<String> cellListDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
List<String> data = cellListDataProvider.getList();
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {

  data.add( String.valueOf(i));
}
cellListDataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellList);
SimplePager pager=new SimplePager();
pager.setDisplay(cellList);
pager.setPageSize(3);
```

Ok, now i ran, at the beginning it shows:

```
1
2
3
```

When i click 1 or 2 or 3 it doesn't jump to next page, that is good no problem

Then i click nextPage, it shows:

```
4
5
6
```

Now I click 4 then nothing happened but if i click 5 or 6 then it automatically jumps to the next page to display though I did not click the nextpgae in `pager`:

```
7
8
9
```

So what is wrong with that?

If i change ButtonCell to TextCell, then there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to DefaultKeyboardSelectionHandler.Check execution of that handler.
You can fix your issue by disabling KeyboardSelectionPolicy of your CellList

```
cellList.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.DISABLED);
```

Comment: thax you, but i think i can use ClickableTextCell() which doesn't have that issue